# CodingBat: without_end

Tags: python, programming-challenge, strings

[Link To Question](https://codingbat.com/prob/p138533)

> Given a string, return a version without the first and last char, so
> "Hello" yields "ell". The string length will be at least 2.
>
> without_end('Hello') → 'ell'
>
> without_end('java') → 'av'
>
> without_end('coding') → 'odin'

This is the code I wrote as a solution to this problem. I feel that this simple of a problem can be written in one line, but I can baffled as to how I can do so; after many attempts. Any and all feedback is appreciated and considered so I can further improve my python practices.

```
def without_end(str):
  
  if len(str) <= 2:
    return ""
    
  no_start = str[1:]
  no_end = no_start[:len(no_start) - 1]
  
  return no_end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were right on track with

```
no_start = str[1:]
no_end = no_start[:len(no_start) - 1]
```

In a first step, they can be combined:

```
return str_[1:len(str_)-1]
```

**Note:** I changed `str` to `str_` because `str` is actually [a datatype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) in Python.

The next thing to know about [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5682996), is that you can use negative indices to index from the back without specifically using the length of the string like so:

```
return str_[1:-1]
```

And since this also works for strings with a length equal to two, you can also get rid of the earlier check.

So your are now down to basically:

```
def without_start_end(input_):
    return input_[1:-1]
```

**Again take note:** `input_` also has the trailing `_`, since, you guessed it, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is already taken.

---

A non-directly code relate side-note: the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (aka PEP8) recommends to use 4 spaces per indentation level, and most people seem to follow that recommendation. There are however exceptions, e.g. Google's TensorFlow framework uses 2 spaces per indentation level (see [their style guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/contribute/code_style)), although Google's own ["general purpose" style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#34-indentation) for Python code sticks with 4 spaces.